# return a video file from aws lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I am processing a 1GB file stored in s3 in AWS Lambda.

The lambda function is being called using API Gateway. Function downloads the s3 file in EFS. Process it. After processing, I want to return the file (as a response to the API request), instead of first uploading it to s3. It is a 1 GB file, which takes ~30min to upload to s3. So I want to avoid it if possible.

Is there a way to return a file from lambda?